# SQL Server: Count number of records on weekly basis (Week = Thursday to Wednesday)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, case

I need some help in writing an SQL in SQL Server where I need to count number of rows group by weeks. There is a tricky description of week which is following 
- For any date before 08/13/2015 the week is of 7 days (i.e. from Thu through Wed) 
- For date 08/13/2015 the week is consider a 9 day week (i.e. from Thursday through Friday so its between 08/13/2015 through 08/21/2015)
- For date 08/22/2015 the week is back to 7 days (i.e. Sat through Friday)

Now having said all the above the result I want to see in my report is the following way . NOTE: WE column in the below attached image is the last day of the week for the range.

[Sample Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Pmq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just write a case statement for the 3 different options. You can find the start day with something like this:

```
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 3,getdate()) / 7, 3) -- Thursdays
DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 5,getdate()) / 7, 5) -- Saturdays
```

The numbers 3 and 5 come from the fact that day 0 (=1.1.1900) is Monday.

If you use this a lot, it might be a good idea to write a inline table valued function to return the dates you need.